# Geocoding Requests - How to add mulitple administrativeArea in componentRestrictions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

According to [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests) we can use administrative_area_level_1, administrative_area_level_2 etc in componentRestrictions.

Then how to add State and District as administrative_area_level_1 and administrative_area_level_2 respectively in the following code ?

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address,
                    'componentRestrictions':{'country':'india'}
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, SCC. Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: Why would you need both? Wouldn't using the more specific one always solve the problem?